# What is wrong with below python code to extract file name?

Tags: python

I have written following python script to rename the folders like
'StudentRecordsData' to 'SRD' (extracted upper case characters and numbers).
If folder name is "Student100Records2". I need output folder like S100R2 and How to avoid FileExistsError?

```
import os
for file_name in os.listdir('.'):    
    # Extracting Upper Case Characters
    uppers = [l for l in file_name if l.isupper()] + [int(x) for x in file_name if x.isdigit()]
    # Extracting Numbers
    #num = [int(x) for x in file_name if x.isdigit()]
    
    if (len(uppers)>2):
        # Renaming the file
        os.rename(file_name, ''.join(uppers))

print('All Files Renamed')
```

Comment: With `os.path.exists()` you can check if a directory or file already exists.

Comment: So you need to rename only folders, but not files? or both?

Comment: You should start earlier. The creation of `uppers` is wrong. Look at the result if you use your example where the file name is "Student100Records2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your creation of `uppers` firstly extracts the upper case letters, then the numbers, so the *Student100Records2* will be *SR1002* instead of *S100R2* after `.join`. And you also combine two lists, where the second one has integers, so the `.join` throws an `TypeError` exception.

The corrected code can be:

```py
uppers = ''.join(x for x in file_name if not x.islower())
```

The `FileExistsError` is raised when the renamed file name already exists in the directory. You can catch this exception and print an information message and then rename it yourself:

```py
try:
    os.rename(file_name, uppers)
except FileExistsError:
    print(f"Cannot rename {file_name}, {uppers} already exists.")
```

The full code can be:

```py
import os

for file_name in os.listdir():
    if __file__.endswith(file_name):
        # We do not want to rename this script
        continue

    uppers = ''.join(x for x in file_name if not x.islower())
    if len(uppers) > 2:
        try:
            os.rename(file_name, uppers)
        except FileExistsError:
            print(f"Cannot rename {file_name}, {uppers} already exists.")
    else:
        print(f"'{uppers}' is too short.")

print("Files renamed")
```

Comment: I would replace `uppers = ''.join(x for x in file_name if not x.islower())` with `uppers = ''.join(x for x in file_name if x.isupper() or x.isdigit())`. Otherwise you will get unwanted special chars like `-` or `_` if they are part of the name.

Comment: Thanks for response. I would like to keep - or _ in directory name.
One more i am basically looking for is:
I have re-written based on your reference and In except FileExistsError, i need counter to be incremented only if destination folder name matches with source name. other cases it should start with _1 for every new exception comes.

Comment: count = 1
temp = os.walk(folder_path, topdown=False)
for root, dirs, files in temp:
    for i in dirs:
        source = os.path.join(root, i)
        Upper_chars = ''.join(x for x in i if not x.islower())
        if len(Upper_chars) > 1:
            try:
                Destination = os.path.join(root, Upper_chars)
                os.rename(source, Destination)
            except FileExistsError:
                Destination = os.path.join(root, Upper_chars+'_'+str(count))
                os.rename(source, Destination)
                count = count + 1

Comment: If I understand correctly, let's imagine that we have 5 folders to rename. The first two were renamed `ABC` and `XYZ`. The third should also be `ABC`, but it can't be because one already exists. It must be renamed to `ABC_1` according to the counter. The fourth should also be renamed `ABC`, but two of them already exist and is so renamed `ABC_2`. The fifth is renamed `XYZ`, but it exists, so it is renamed `XYZ_1` and **not** `XYZ_3`. I'm right?